# Time for a room to be heated with various heat sinks and sources

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conduction

I have a question where I have to calculate the time for a room to reach a certain temp. The room is heated using a heater and there are internal fixtures which absorb heat, aswell as heat loss to the walls. For the internal fixtures, all I have is the mass and specific heat capacity, whilst for the walls I have the R value. I am confused as the properties given for the internal fixtures can not give me rate of change, for example if I use the equation Q = mc delta T, this gives me the total heat absorbed, but not the rate. In order to find the rate of change, I will need to know the time, but to find the time I will need the rate of change. Please help

Comment: What do you get if you take the time derivative of your equation?

Comment: Try Newton's Law of cooling.

Comment: You need to know a lot more details like wattage of your heater, size of the room, area of the walls

Comment: I was wondering if since I have the equation Q = mcdeltaT/t and Q = AdeltaT/R whether I can set these equal to find the time for it to heat? As I know the heater wattage